# How can I refer to the function in structure of class in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, structure

I'd like to use the getSth function which returns `struct aa` type in `main()`.
Would you let me know the way to refer it?

```
//info.h
namespace nsp {
  class A {
    struct Info {
      struct aa {
        std::string str;
        int num;
        aa(): num(0) {}
      };
      std::vector<aa> aas;
      aa getSth();
    };
  };
}

//info.cpp
A::Info::aa A::Info::getSth() {
aa ret;
for(auto &tmp: aas) {
  if(ret.num < aas.num)
    ret.num = aas.num;
}
return ret;
}

// main.cpp
#include info.h
namepace nsp {
  class A;
}
int main()
{
  nsp::A *instance = new nsp::A();
  // How can I refer getSth using "instance"?
  .....
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply put, **you can't**. You declared `getSth` inside a nested struct of type `Info` but didn't declare any data members of that type. So there's no object to call `nsp::A::Info::getSth` against.

What's worse, you declared `A` as a `class` and didn't provide an access specifier. A class's members are all `private` without an access specifier, so `getSth` can't be accessed outside the class. If you had done it this way instead:

```
class A {
  // other stuff; doesn't matter
  public:
  aa getSth();
};
```

well then, you could have accessed it from `main` like this:

```
int main()
{
  nsp::A *instance = new nsp::A();
  // now it's accessible
  instance->getSth();
  // deliberate memory leak to infuriate pedants
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm glad you want to improve my answer, but I really prefer my own writing style.

Comment: I apologize for overstepping. It's just that phrases like "if you had done" seem way to passive (and even verbose) for the idea you are trying to express.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But **info.h** cannot be fixed now. Do you have any idea regarding the way to fix only main?

Comment: @beginner If you've left something (such as the declaration of an  `Info` object) out of the declaration of `A`, edit it in and we may be able to spot a way out. If not, you're just out of luck,